# Locating the "media" directory in the home directory on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, directory

I need to find the "media" directory somewhere in the home directory.  I can't see it as a directory or sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Sidebar was closed and "other locations" (>>>>>>>>"computer") icon was not visible.